# I'm in grade 9 vacation and I decided that I want to be a mathematician when I grow up can you suggest me hard exercices to do?

Tags: soft-question

I'm in grade 9 vacation and I decided that I want to be a mathematician when I grow up can you suggest me  hard exercices to do?

Comment: Well, I think you're already starting up quite well by coming to Mathematics SE. Just hang around and read the problems that people post :) You will see topics that you know nothing or very little about, and that can give you ideas what to study next.

Comment: While I really like the motivation of your question, I have voted to close it because I feel it is just not the kind of questions that can get a useful answer on this site. For one thing, without knowing you, your background and your interests, we can't really give you a meaningful list of exercises to do. And even with this knowledge there would probably be hundreds of possible exercises that one could suggest you. Perhaps you'd get more useful help by asking your math teacher for some suggestions.

Comment: @ArnaudD.: nothing like encouraging the youngsters, eh? Selim, don't listen to this curmudgeon!

Comment: Perhaps helpful would be to look over some of [these problems](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3158_usa_contests).

Comment: If you feel like working ahead on your school mathematics, you could try [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/). They have some really good videos and it's free as well.

Comment: Try to practice the fundamental concepts of Algebra and Arithmetic without a calculator. Try to learn Geometry fundamentals well.

Answer (score 4):

I myself have just cleared grade 10 and so I can relate to your situation. My suggestion would be to try for your respective country's Math Olympiad. So basically when you prepare for it, it develops your mind and thinking capacity at a very different level. It makes school maths look easy. And as Matti P. commented, you have started well by joining Mathematics SE. Hope it helps!